# Feasibility of data visualisation tool based on games played by user via google play game API

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am a complete beginner in android development and for self-learning purposes thinking of creating a visualisation tool where different progress graphs of user's high score vs time or latest scores among all games will be displayed. The game in observation can be any game selected by user from the list of all games played by him till date. I just want to know is this possible to do in google play games API? If yes how can I do so? i.e. displaying high score or latest score from any game played by him till date?

Answer (score 0):

Using google play games API this would not be possible to get data of other games played by user.